# Were silver highlights added to Darth Vader's helmet to make its surface seem more reflective?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, production

In the Original Trilogy, the costumes used for Darth Vader's helmet were not all black, but had silver highlights applied in an alternating pattern:

[image]

<sub>Screenshot from *A New Hope* ([via Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/tq10fq/you_can_really_see_the_imperfections_in_darth/))</sub>

The effect is subtle, but can be seen when looking closely at the lower cheek and jaw pieces on the viewer's left, and the nose bridge and upper cheek on the viewer's right. I found a fan-made diagram outlining where the highlights were applied (note that this is mirrored when compared to the above shot):

[image]

<sub>Fan analysis from http://thepropden.aokforums.com/</sub>

This is interesting to me because I've watched these movies countless times and never noticed that the helmet was anything other than uniformly glossy black, as in more recent and higher-budget incarnations of the costume.

**Question:** Was this a common filmmaking technique at the time the original films were made, and meant to convey that the helmet was fully black and reflective? Or was the helmet meant to be matte black and silver in-universe, and, like [C-3PO's silver leg](https://screencrush.com/c3po-silver-leg/), this was easily missed and changed in later costume designs?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diegetic

Comment: I don't know how to improve your title, but "diegetic" doesn't mean what your question implies. Something is "diegetic" if it can be heard/seen by the characters of the movie. These highlights can be seen by characters, so they are by definition diegetic. An example of "non-diegetic" is the eyes of replicants in Blade Runner: the "reflection" is only meant to be seen by the audience, it's not truly something replicant eyes do.

Comment: @AndresF.: It’s not clear to me that the highlights can be seen by the characters. The essence of the question is whether the characters see the highlights, or if the characters see an all-black helmet, and the highlights are a special effect that makes the helmet “look right” on camera, where the details of an all-black helmet might get lost in the  recording process.

Comment: @AndresF. Thanks for the rewording—I agree that that's clearer. That said, RLH is correct that whether the highlights are meant to exist within the world of the film is exactly what the question is trying to establish.

Comment: https://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/movies/how-darth-vaders-helmet-from-the-original-1977-star-wars-was-found-in-australia-20161217-gtd7mv.html - HIs helmet very clearly has silver on the grill; https://static.ffx.io/images/$zoom_1%2C$multiply_0.513%2C$ratio_1.777778%2C$width_1996%2C$x_4%2C$y_157/t_crop_custom/q_86%2Cf_auto/9d21fb2bbecf658d878bea3ece071f76fe458ac2

Comment: Considering there were something like three variants of R2-D2's dome alone in the first movie, I'm not sure if you can get an all-encompassing answer.

Comment: @RLH I agree it's borderline, but if the highlights can be "seen" by the characters, then they are diegetic; and there's no reason to doubt they can see them, as Vader's helmet is meant to be a reflective/polished surface (it's based on a samurai helmet, after all). Whether silver highlights were added by paintbrush beyond what natural light would cause to enhance the effect or whether they are natural lights, I think it's the same: the characters are meant to see Vader's helmet is reflective. It's the same with lightsabers: the effect is added in post-prod, but every character can see them.

Comment: @AndresF. That it was meant to be reflective is certainly one interpretation, but it's also possible that the helmet was meant to literally have a matte checkerboard-like pattern instead, which was ignored/revised in later versions of the costume. Put another way: Was it just meant to be a visual effect? Or was it like the silver leg or [Max Rebo](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-mysteries-getting-to-the-bottom-of-max-rebo) where a "weird" design was interpreted by audiences as a "normal" one?

Comment: @MiloP (cool about Max Rebo, didn't know that). In either case, what you're asking about Vader's helmet would be diegetic (i.e. seen by the character). It can be that it's a checkered pattern; or it can be enhanced reflections; it can be some third thing. But there's absolutely no basis for assuming the characters cannot see this, just like they can see lightsabers glow, which is SFX. So your question is good, "was this meant to represent highlights, or does Vader helmet have actual silver painted areas?", but in all cases it's diegetic.

Comment: It's not so much that it makes it look more "reflective", it's more that it picks up the highlights to better define the shape and silhouette through the use of contrast. Things that would get a little lost and muddled if it was photographed as all black, as it's clearly intended to be.